# HTML Form doing a GET request intermittently with passwords visible in the browser history

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, post

We are building a register page which is a django populated form with two empty boxes to enter/confirm password. This form is then intercepted when submit is clicked and an Ajax call is performed. But in some cases the browser(Chrome)is making a get call with the form data and also making the API call. This is obviously dangerous because the password will be visible in plain text in the URL. e.preventDefault is also not preventing this GET call. Here is my current code:

```
    <form class="form-signin" id="provisionForm" name="provisionForm" ng-submit="submit()">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Register</h2> {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form.as_p }}
          <div class="registrationFormAlert" id="divCheckPasswordMatch"></div>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Register</button>
      </form>


    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#id_confirm_password").keyup(function() {
                    var password = $("#id_password").val();
                    $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html(password == $(this).val() ? "" : "Passwords do not match!");
                });
            $("#id_password,#id_confirm_password").tooltip();
            var options = {};
            options.ui = {
                bootstrap2: false,
                showErrors: false,
                showVerdicts: true,
            };
            $("#provisionForm").submit(function(e)
                {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var frm = $('#provisionForm');
                    var url = '/register/'
                    $('#id_first_name').removeAttr('disabled');
                    $('#id_email').removeAttr('disabled');
                    $('#id_last_name').removeAttr('disabled');
                    $('#id_tenant_name').removeAttr('disabled');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: url,
                        data: frm.serialize(),
                        processData:false,
                        success: function (data) {
                            /*if (signup)
                                alert('Thank you for completing the registration process. Our support team will be in touch via email to inform you when your account is ready for use.');*/
                            window.location.href = data.href;
                        },
                        error: function(data) {
                            if (data.status == 491){
                                var obj = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
                                alert(obj.msg);
                            }else{
                                $('#regDiv').html(data.responseText);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                $('#id_first_name').attr('disabled','disabled');
                $('#id_email').attr('disabled','disabled');
                $('#id_last_name').attr('disabled','disabled');
                $('#id_tenant_name').attr('disabled','disabled');
                return false;
                })
        });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: Why are you calling submit() method in ng-submit when you are already using jQuery? Also looks like url is wrong. You need to specify the whole API url including domain.

Comment: I don't know but a temporary fix would be to add `method="POST"` to the form to at least make sure it doesn't do a GET.

Comment: I tried without ng-submit(). No difference. There is no submit() function defined btw.

Comment: Change url prop to complete url of your API.

Comment: The form's URL is a large UPN based register link. Putting form method to post is posting data to the same URL which is throwing 400 because that does not expect anything

Comment: @TusharArora: That is the complete URL of the API. server-host/register/. That API gets called successfully and data also comes back. The issue is with this GET call which happens once in a while.

Comment: Why are you returning false in the submit callback? I do not think there is a need for that. I cannot tell the exact problem as your html does not match the JS code that you posted.